# How do I put the name of the file in advance when uploading?

Tags: php

I want to save the uploaded file with **1.jpg** name. If it already exists in the "upload" folder, save with **2.jpg**,

If file **2.jpg** already exists in the "upload" folder, wait until the another script clears one of them. If, after some time (about 120 seconds), none of the two files was erased, it will display an error message. What code should I use?

My code is:

```
<?php
    // Check if the form was submitted
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

        // Check if file was uploaded without errors
        if(isset($_FILES["photo"]) && $_FILES["photo"]["error"] == 0){
            $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
            $filename = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];
            $filetype = $_FILES["photo"]["type"];
            $filesize = $_FILES["photo"]["size"];

            // Verify file extension
            $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

            // Verify file size - 5MB maximum
            $maxsize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
            if($filesize > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

            // Verify MYME type of the file
            if(in_array($filetype, $allowed)){

                // Check whether file exists before uploading it
                if(file_exists("upload/" . $filename)){
                    echo $filename . " is already exists.";
                } else{
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $filename);
                    echo "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again.";
            }
        } else{
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["photo"]["error"];
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: show us what you have now

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I put the code I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ensure that PHP is configured to allow file uploads. In *php.ini* file, search for the file_uploads directive, and set it to On. Then update your code as follows.

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"]);

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    file_rename(); // Call for your other script
}
else{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $filename);
    echo "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
}
```